# freecurrencyapi getting value from dict to output currency amount based on amount entered

Tags: python, json

I've been trying to get to the amount for the currency exchange, however, my terminal is giving errors about the requests.
I'm output goal is to put the input amount, then times it by the currency exchange rate in the API.

Here is the parameters that I'm using: https://freecurrencyapi.com/docs/latest#request-parameters

```
import freecurrencyapi
import json

#This was made from this API: https://freecurrencyapi.com/docs/

#Currencies are based on the value of the USD
client = freecurrencyapi.Client('API Key')

currencyamount = int(input('Enter amount: '))

result = client.latest('base_currency')

for i in response.json()['data']:
    print(i['currencies'])
```

I have looked at numerous related-ish Stack Overflow questions/answers along with w3schools, but none seemed to help solve my problem.